# Sync users between two microsoft azure AD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

Is there any way to sync one Microsoft Azure Active Directory users to another Microsoft Azure Active Directory in c#?

Answer (score 0):

Since your domain name have to be unique, I don't think it's possible.

Azure Connect does synchronization between on-premise and azure ad, but not between two azure ad.